# GTK comboBox flowing to fill vertical space in toolbar

Tags: gtk, pygtk

I'm building a toolbar in PyGTK and attaching a combo box to it.  The result that I got is that the combo box stretches to fill all the vertical space available:

[image: ComboBox filling up all vertical toolbar space]

I have been trying every trick in the book that I can think of in order to avoid it, but I'm starting to admit that maybe it's just GTK style and I won't be able to get rid of it.

I can post some code but this should be quite simple to recreate.  Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the combobox in a `gtk.Alignment`.  You can create the latter with 0.5 vertical alignment to have the combobox centered vertically.

Comment: Wonderful!!  I didn't know that gtk.Alignment did that.  Many thanks!!